# Difference between link and postLink in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to cakephp. Please bear with me. I want to know what is the difference between

```
$this->Html->link();
```

And

```
$this->Form->postLink();
```

As i have seen both of them will output anchor tag only. What makes the use of postLink() over link() ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case (`Html->link()`), you have only a link to a URL. If it starts with "http://", it is treated as external, else it should follow the convention `controller/action/view`.

In the second case (`Form->postLink()`), you create a `<form>` element so it will be passed in `$_GET[]` or `$_POST[]` depending on the options you set - default is `POST`.

All the info [here](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html) from Cakephp API.

Comment: one more point - postLink method creates a <form> element. If you want to use this method inside of an existing form, you must use the inline or block options so that the new form can be rendered outside of its parent. [source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)